# Do CS PhD admissions consider the time it took to get a degree?

Tags: phd, masters

In my case, I have the option to either extend my Bachelor's or get a Master's before applying to PhD. Since both options will take the same amount of time, I am concerned that the admissions committee will hold me to a higher standard if I do end up getting a Master's, even though I would technically be finishing the degree in fewer years than normal. Do you recommend that I still go for the degree even though I will definetly want a PhD in the future? Is this something that I can/should clarify in my SoP if I do go for the Master's?

Edit: Turns out that I will need a Master's for some of the PhD programs I am interested in

Edit 2: I'm in the US

Comment: Which country is this?

Answer (score 1):

I won't comment on what you should do, as it is a personal decision. I'd suggest making it on your judgement about what is best for your education.

But in a case like you describe I can't see any reason for a committee to think that either was an advantage or disadvantage.

In some places, having a MS is sort of expected for doctoral admission. In others it isn't. I think the time would only be a factor if it took an extraordinarily long time to get a degree or there was a long gap between the previous degree and the application. That usually requires explanation but isn't necessarily disqualifying.

I assume you would probably learn a bit more by working toward the MS, but you have to judge that. But I think you can make the decision based on educational principles without feeling at risk.